# ChartJS:align zeros on chart with multi axes

Tags: chart.js

How to align zeros on chart with multi axes, if there are both positive and negative values in dataset?

I want zeroes to be on the same line.

I dont like this:
[Graph image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tWl6r.jpg)

[link to jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gtmvkq4n/)

```
new Chart(canvas, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'A',
      yAxisID: 'A',
      data: [-10, 96, 84, 76, 69]
    }, {
      label: 'B',
      yAxisID: 'B',
      data: [-2, 3, 5, 2, 3]
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        id: 'A',
        type: 'linear',
        position: 'left',
      }, {
        id: 'B',
        type: 'linear',
        position: 'right',

      }]
    }
  }
});
```

actualy, The example on the official web page has the same problem. Looks so messy.

Comment: What have you done until now? Show your code?

Comment: I added code and a link to the jsfiddle example

Comment: actualy, The example on the official web page has the same problem. Looks so messy. http://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/charts/bar/multi-axis.html

Answer (score 6):

The answer above is great if you know the ranges in advance and can specify min and max for each ticks object in advance. If, like me, you're trying to produce the effect with generated data, you'll need something that computes these values for you. The following does this without recourse to hard-coded values. It does generate ugly max / min values - but there's another fix for that: [Hide min and max values from y Axis in Chart.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43063407/hide-min-and-max-values-from-y-axis-in-chart-js). It may also generate less than ideal spacing in which case a simple fudge factor applied to the min and max values may be used.

```
function scaleDataAxesToUnifyZeroes (datasets, options) {
  let axes = options.scales.yAxes
  // Determine overall max/min values for each dataset
  datasets.forEach(function (line) {
    let axis = line.yAxisID ? axes.filter(ax => ax.id === line.yAxisID)[0] : axes[0]
    axis.min_value = Math.min(...line.data, axis.min_value || 0)
    axis.max_value = Math.max(...line.data, axis.max_value || 0)
  })
  // Which gives the overall range of each axis
  axes.forEach(axis => {
    axis.range = axis.max_value - axis.min_value
    // Express the min / max values as a fraction of the overall range
    axis.min_ratio = axis.min_value / axis.range
    axis.max_ratio = axis.max_value / axis.range
  })
  // Find the largest of these ratios
  let largest = axes.reduce((a, b) => ({
    min_ratio: Math.min(a.min_ratio, b.min_ratio),
    max_ratio: Math.max(a.max_ratio, b.max_ratio)
  }))
  // Then scale each axis accordingly
  axes.forEach(axis => {
    axis.ticks = axis.ticks || { }
    axis.ticks.min = largest.min_ratio * axis.range
    axis.ticks.max = largest.max_ratio * axis.range
  })
}
```

Comment: This works great, also thanks for the tip on hiding the min and max value.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by setting the `ticks` option on your axes to control the max, min, and stepSize.  To make the zeros align, you need to make the axes symmetric.  `stepSize` is optional if you want the gridlines to be aligned as well.

In your example:

```
yAxes: [{
    id: 'A',
    type: 'linear',
    position: 'left',
    ticks : {
        max: 100,
        min: -50,
        stepSize: 50
    }
  }, {
    id: 'B',
    type: 'linear',
    position: 'right',
    ticks : {
        max: 6,
        min: -3,
        stepSize: 3 
    }
  }]
```

See updated fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/x885kpe1/1/